# Multiline underlined button

Tags: css, button, flexbox, underline, box-shadow

I am having issues with underlining button text using box-shadow and wrapping it on multiple lines. It should be solved using just CSS.

Needs to use the following HTML (can't add HTML tags, special characters etc.):

```
  <button class="button">
    <span class="button__inner">
      <span class="button__text">
        Button with very very very long example text
      </span>
      <svg class="button__icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </button>
```

[Visually it should look like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTCqP.png)

Requirements:

1. Use **box-shadow** to underline text on multiple lines.
2. Do not add additional HTML (needs to use HTML structure provided above).
3. <s>.button__inner has to be display: flex or inline-flex.</s>
4. The icon needs to be aligned right (in its own column), vertically centered and not have underline.

```css
.button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.button__inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
}

.button__text {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px currentColor;
}
.button:hover .button__text {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.button__icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 200px">

  <p>
    Following button using correct HTML, however box-shadow does not underline correctly on multiple lines. The icon needs to be on the right in its own column so therefore adding display: inline; to .button__inner is not an option.
  </p>

  <button class="button">
    <span class="button__inner">
      <span class="button__text">
        Button with very very very long example text
      </span>
      <svg class="button__icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </button>

  <p>
    Below is the visually desired result, however it uses an additional span element. How to achieve this using just CSS and without altering the HTML?
  </p>

  <button class="button">
    <span class="button__inner">
      <span>
        <span class="button__text">
          Button with very very very long example text
        </span>
      </span>
      <svg class="button__icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Is this even possible using just CSS?

Comment: why the button need to be flex? and why box-shadow? You are setting many *overkill* requirements and I am pretty sure what you want at the end can be done without all these requirements.

Comment: What would you suggest to use then instead of flex to achieve this icon's placement?
Instead of box-shadow   text-decoration: underline; & text-decoration-skip-ink: none; are possible, text-decoration-skip-ink doesn't have as good browser support as box-shadow does. (The underline can't be split under letters p, g and such)

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question to focus on what you want to achieve instead of restricting the use of specific properties. You have no idea what can be done with CSS, there is a lot of way to get underline without box-shadow and without text-decoration too. Same for the alignment.

Comment: I agree, it is an overkill for a simple looking button. I guess the answer to my question is a no, it can't be done with these requirements, right? I can edit the requirements by removing the need to use flex necessarily

Comment: Simply don't set requirements. As I told you, you may not know all the CSS properties so don't restrict to the use of what you know. Simply tell us what you want to achieve and you will get a plenty of answers (then it's up to you to use the most suitable one)

Comment: The requirements aren't made up by me, rather told by a more experienced senior front-end developer, that this could be definitely achieved using box-shadow and not adding additional elements to HTML. I myself doubt it could achieved too. I have ~5 years of experience in strictly front-end development.

Comment: as uou like, I tried to help to get an answer (PS: here is at least 4 different ways without box-shadow and without extra element to create underlines: https://jsfiddle.net/e0bhLa1x/1/, if I had time I can for sure find more than this .. we are also experienced here)

Comment: Thanks, I truly appreciate your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it work in your case to use `text-decoration: underline` instead of `box-shadow`? like this example: https://codepen.io/annaazzam/pen/PoZEJwX